# Set background image in v-for using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I am trying to add a CSS background image to a dynamic `style` block using `require` in Vue.js and `v-for`.

```
  <div v-for='item of this.$store.state.offers'
       :key="item.id"
       :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + require('../../assets/men.jpg') + ')'}"
  >
```

The thing is that the code above works statically, but if I replace it with `${item.img}` in the `require` brackets, it breaks down. Is there a way?

Comment: What's in `item.img`? Is it a file name, like `men.jpg`, or a file path, like `../../assets.men.jog`?

Comment: It may be informative if you could also post the code that doesn't work. Just from the description it is difficult to be sure exactly what you're doing.

Comment: item.img is a file path, the same as written in require brakets

Comment: This code does not work to me  <div v-for='item of this.$store.state.offers'
       :key="item.id"
       :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + require('`${item.img}`') + ')'}"
  >

Comment: `${}` works with "template strings" _(you put it inside regulrar)_, but you don't need it in this case: `:style="{'background-image': 'url(' + require(item.img) + ')'}"`

Comment: When I am using require(item.img) it returns the Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '../../assets/men.jpg'". It seems that case pathe should be different...

Comment: I don't see the point of using `require` in style, only one thing comes to mind is `base64`, but this is just a guess. Could you explain please?

Comment: This code comes from the internet, I tried it with static path and it worked out. I do not know at the moment other options...

Comment: @artanik The reason for `require` is that Webpack bundles Vue assets and renames them with a hash, so the CSS would point to a non-existent image name otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each of your images has the path as you've written it statically, you could do this:

```
:style="{'background-image': 'url(' + require(`${item.img}`) + ')'}"
```

OR

```
:style="{'background-image': 'url(' + require('' + item.img) + ')'}"
```

OR

If you want to just use the filename in the image with no path, you can do this:

```
:style="{'background-image': 'url(' + require('@/assets/' + item.img) + ')'}"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already tied those options. All the time Vue crashes with "Error: Cannot find module '../../assets/picture.jpg'"...

Comment: They all work, guaranteed, unless your paths are wrong.  Are you completely sure you already tried `'' + item.img`?  And if you tried with the `@` you wouldn't get that crash message...

Comment: Thank you so much, :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + require('@/assets/' + item.img) + ')'}" works!!!